# Cannot call API from localhost:4200 - Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular project. I need to test API call from the Angular app but it's not working. It returns me error,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://...../api/v1/user/authen' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

On the Sever has already set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'**

I also made a simple html+Jquery file to test calling API and it works perfectly.

```
  function callApi(){
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://..../api/v1/user/authen',
      data: {
        "user": "admin",
        "password": "123456"
      },
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
  }
```

But from the Angular APP I still got the error. Is there anything I need to specifically set on Angular app ?

Comment: The problem is probably on the server. Maybe the framework has missed the access control allow origin somehow. You should probably post the server code

Comment: we have to enable CORS from the api or the server side.  This is not an issue with the angular code.

Comment: quick check - 1) are we calling the correct api? 2) in the chrome network tab for api, can we see Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*' ? questions from my experience

Comment: What language you're using in back end? can you show us some back end code where you added  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a problem with the server itself, it's not allowing to access API form `localhost:4200.`
You can run your app by disabling google chrome security and try to hit the API.

Open the Run in your windows machine and paste the link below for disabling web security and try to hit API.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmpChromeSession"
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Macbook.

Comment: I haven't used in mac but you can try this in your Macbook.   open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security

Comment: If API works fine in disabled security mode then there is some problem in server site Allow access origin code.

Comment: Nice, It's works!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand clearly but I solve it by adding **JSON.stringify()** to the payload.

```
  login(credential) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>( 
    this.baseUrl + '/user/authen', JSON.stringify(credential)
    )
    .pipe( 
      map( res => res ),
      catchError( this.handleError )
    );
  }
```